# How to give same styles in all html template of a module in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

1. To set a global styling in SPA made by Angular 2 we can put the css link in index.html file.
2. To set styles for individual component we can add styling in styles or styleUrls in each component's Component Decorator function.
3. We can also give similar styling to different component by importing common .css file in different component too.

I have multiple NgModule in my app. What I want to do is use a common styling which will be applied module wise.

For example: module1.css for Module1 and Module2.css for Module2 without having to import css in each component.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an top level component in each of your ngModules, applying module1.css, module2.css... to each of the top level component's css would do the trick.

e.g. Let's say the below component `app-root` is the top level component in module1.

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: [
    '../assets/module1.css',
    './app.component.css'
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm. Nice that might do. Will get back after I try this.

Comment: Didn't work sadly. The style of parent component wont be inherited by child component